# context of a Niels Bohr quote "some subjects are so serious that one can only joke about them"

Tags: bohr

I saw this quote today...

> “Some subjects are so serious that one can only joke about them.”

It is attributed to Niels Bohr.

What was the subject referred to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This quote has a single attestation, p.24 of the book "The genius of science : a portrait gallery" (2000) by Abraham Pais, a physicist who would be in a position to know, having been Bohr's assistant.  I have examined an online library copy of the book.  Pais mentions the quote in a discussion of Bohr's philosophical beliefs, specifically his codification of "complementarity" (pp.21-24), the idea that a full description of an entity may entail properties that are mutually exclusive to each other (such as the wave-particle duality of photons).  To be specific, it seems the quote relates to Bohr's characterization of an "expert" as one who hones their knowledge in a specific area until they know "everything about nothing," and a "philosopher" as one who broadens their ken until they know "nothing about everything."  Pais's introduction of the quote comes right after he relates a favorite story of Bohr's, concerning a student who is certain the lecture he just attended was the "finest" ever, because neither he nor the lecturer understood the topic at all.  So the quote doesn't seem to have been directed at any specific subject.  I hope that helps.